# problem with downloading with yt-dlp, getting time out error

Tags: download, youtube-api, command-line-interface, youtube-dl, manjaro

i tried to download from youtube with yt-dlp, and got an error:
i've made sure i have yt-dlp installed and i also removed and installed it again ,

```
sudo pacman -Qi yt-dlp   
Version         : 2021.12.27-1
```

and im using windscribe vpn too,

the error is:

```
 yt-dlp -F https://www.youtube.com/watch\?v=-bt_y4Loofg                                                                                                                                                                       ✔ 
[youtube] -bt_y4Loofg: Downloading webpage
WARNING: [youtube] Unable to download webpage: <urlopen error timed out>
[youtube] -bt_y4Loofg: Downloading android player API JSON
WARNING: [youtube] <urlopen error timed out>. Retrying ...
[youtube] -bt_y4Loofg: Downloading android player API JSON (retry #1)
WARNING: [youtube] <urlopen error timed out>. Retrying ...
[youtube] -bt_y4Loofg: Downloading android player API JSON (retry #2)
WARNING: [youtube] <urlopen error timed out>. Retrying ...
[youtube] -bt_y4Loofg: Downloading android player API JSON (retry #3)
[youtube] -bt_y4Loofg: Downloading iframe API JS
WARNING: [youtube] Unable to download webpage: <urlopen error timed out>
[youtube] -bt_y4Loofg: Downloading web player API JSON
WARNING: [youtube] <urlopen error timed out>. Retrying ...
[youtube] -bt_y4Loofg: Downloading web player API JSON (retry #1)
WARNING: [youtube] <urlopen error timed out>. Retrying ...
[youtube] -bt_y4Loofg: Downloading web player API JSON (retry #2)
WARNING: [youtube] <urlopen error timed out>. Retrying ...
[youtube] -bt_y4Loofg: Downloading web player API JSON (retry #3)
WARNING: [youtube] Unable to download API page: <urlopen error timed out> (caused by URLError(TimeoutError('timed out')))
ERROR: [youtube] -bt_y4Loofg: Unable to download API page: <urlopen error timed out> (caused by URLError(TimeoutError('timed out'))) (caused by URLError(TimeoutError('timed out')))
```

and i also tried with vpn off, and with youtube-dl too and it still didn't work,
here's the youtube-dl error:

```
youtube-dl  -F https://www.youtube.com/watch\?v=-bt_y4Loofg                                                                                                                                                        1 ✘  31s  
[youtube] -bt_y4Loofg: Downloading webpage
WARNING: Unable to download webpage: <urlopen error [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer>
[youtube] -bt_y4Loofg: Downloading API JSON
ERROR: Unable to download API page: <urlopen error [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer> (caused by URLError(ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer')))
```

i tried both with the url between single quotations and dbl-quotations and also without quotations but special characters scaped, so url doesn't seem to be the problem
and neither yt-dlp nor youtube-dl are working, so that's something to note,

and when i debug it with -v :

```
yt-dlp -v https://www.youtube.com/watch\?v=-bt_y4Loofg                                                                                                                                                                     1 ✘ 
[debug] Command-line config: ['-v', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-bt_y4Loofg']
[debug] Encodings: locale UTF-8, fs utf-8, out utf-8, err utf-8, pref UTF-8
[debug] yt-dlp version 2021.12.27 [6223f67a8]
[debug] Python version 3.10.1 (CPython 64bit) - Linux-5.15.16-1-MANJARO-x86_64-with-glibc2.33
[debug] exe versions: ffmpeg 4.4.1 (setts), ffprobe 4.4.1, rtmpdump 2.4
[debug] Optional libraries: Cryptodome, secretstorage, mutagen, sqlite, websockets
[debug] Proxy map: {}
[debug] [youtube] Extracting URL: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-bt_y4Loofg
[youtube] -bt_y4Loofg: Downloading webpage
WARNING: [youtube] Unable to download webpage: <urlopen error [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer>
[youtube] -bt_y4Loofg: Downloading android player API JSON
WARNING: [youtube] <urlopen error [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer>. Retrying ...
[youtube] -bt_y4Loofg: Downloading android player API JSON (retry #1)
WARNING: [youtube] <urlopen error [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer>. Retrying ...
[youtube] -bt_y4Loofg: Downloading android player API JSON (retry #2)
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow! This platform aims to help developers of software to discuss their coding / programming problems. Your question might be more suitable on another StackExchange Platform like https://superuser.com/